# Большой массив через Ajax в PHP

Tags: php, ajax

у меня через ajax передаются 9 значений и массив из 1100 элементов. Но до сервера доходит только массив из 991 элемента. max_input_vars в php.ini я установил в 5000, но вcе равно до сервера не доходит полный массив. В чем проблема? Всем спасибо за помощь

Comment: Какой запрос? POST или GET?

Comment: так поди элемент не просто число а объект какой-нибудь.

Answer (score 0):

Отправляйте всё это как json строку. А на сервере делайте `json_decode($data, true)` и не придётся мучиться с количеством переменных